# The sort! result is not expected, is there anything wrong with my code?

Tags: dolphindb

when I want to sort! a vector, the result is not correct,is my code written wrong?
 my code like this ,

```
def TL_arange(s1,s2,s3){
         ns=[]
           clear!(ns)
         n=s1
         do {ns.append!(n)
              n=n+s3;}
         while(n<=s2);
                return ns
     }
    A=TL_arange(0.01,0.06,0.005)
    B=take(A,20)
    C=sort!(B)
```

**the C is like this :**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The function TL_arrange returns a tuple instead of a regular array. That is the reason the sort! doesn't work.

Comment: nice catch, you are right. if I rewrite like " ns=array(DOUBLE)" , I get the correct result.